# validation of form embed

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I have a form using a collection of embed forms.

In my main form, i have a validation on a field "comment". This validation, simple, works fine.
My collection of embed form treat another entity. I would like to have a validation on this entity field

```
|  comment (min length = 5 ok) ------
                                    |   anotherfield (min length = 5 not ok)    
                                    |   anotherfield (min length = 5 not ok)
```

I call the two form validations rules by the validation.yml file:

```
My\Bundle\Entity\Main:
    properties:
        comment:
            - Length: 
                min: 5
                minMessage: "minmessage"

My\Bundle\Entity\EmbedEntity:
    properties:
        anotherfield:
            - Length: 
                min: 5
                minMessage: "minmessage"
```

But the second validation is just ignored and my form is commited. (no errors returned and go through `$form is->valid()` )

My validation file is read. (my first validation on comment is fine)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`"cascade_validation" => true` in your parent form should make the embedded form be validated.

Also I think you can add a `Valid` to the embedded field in your validation file to get it to work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Valid constraint to validate objects embedded as properties on the parent object

e.g. if using annotations

```
/**
*
* @Assert\Valid
*/
private $items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'error_bubbling'=>true, to the property , displays also the minMessages.
for example:

```
$builder->add('title', null, array('error_bubbling'=>true,"mapped" => true, "description" => "The title of the position"))
```

In the colletion builder->add call:

```
   $builder->add(
            'positionOwners',
            'collection',
            array(
                'type' => new PositionOwnerType($this->positionOwnerFormSubscriber),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'mapped' => true,
                'error_bubbling'=>true,
            'cascade_validation' => true
            )
        )
```

Also, setDefaultOptions should look like this:

```
 /**
 * Set the default options of PositionType form
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'data_class' => 'Radsphere\RecruitmentBundle\Entity\PositionType',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'error_bubbling'=>true
        )
    );
}
```